# coldfusion performance comparison: custom tag versus function

Tags: performance, function, memory, coldfusion, custom-tag

On my test box I have ColdFusion 10 and have allocated just 1gig: "Maximum JVM Heap Size (in MB) = 1024".

I have a process that loops around 1000 times.  Each loop iteration calls a custom tag ~200 times.  So in all about 200,000 calls.  The process never finishes, I eventually run out of memory.  I'm sure it's what I'm doing inside the tags that is the problem and not the tags themselves.  But I wanted to prove that.  I ran this test and it seems that ColdFusion functions are much faster `2.7secs` as opposed to `14.6secs`.  The test just increments a number.

My question is: **Does this appear to be a valid test?**  If functions are so much faster should it be a rule of thumb to use them instead of custom tags whenever possible?

**test results:**

```
x = 0
Running good customtag 1000000 times...
x = 1000000
Time to complete: 14627

x = 0
Running good function 1000000 times...
x = 1000001
Time to complete: 2793
```

**good.cfm custom tag:**

```
<cfparam name="ATTRIBUTES.x" type="numeric" default="0">

<cfif thisTag.ExecutionMode eq "end">
    <cfset request.x = ATTRIBUTES.x+1>
    <cfset thistag.generatedcontent = "">
</cfif>
```

**test code:**

```
<cffunction name="good" output="false" returntype="Numeric" access="private">
    <cfargument name="numIn" type="numeric" required="true">
    <cfset var x = 0>
    <cfset x = arguments.numIn + 1>
    <cfreturn x>
</cffunction>

<cfset loopNum = 1000000>
<cfset request.x = 0>

<cfoutput>
    x = #request.x#<br>
    Running good customtag #loopNum# times...<br>
</cfoutput>
<cfset tBegin = GetTickCount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="#loopNum#" index="i">
    <cf_good x="#request.x#"></cf_good>
</cfloop>
<cfset tEnd = GetTickCount()>
<cfset scriptTime = (tEnd - tBegin)>
<cfoutput>
    x = #request.x#<br>
    Time to complete: #scriptTime#<br>
</cfoutput>

<cfset request.x = 0>
<cfoutput>
    x = #request.x#<br>
    Running good function #loopNum# times...<br>
</cfoutput>
<cfset tBegin = GetTickCount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="#loopNum#" index="i">
    <cfset request.x = good(i)>
</cfloop>
<cfset tEnd = GetTickCount()>
<cfset scriptTime = (tEnd - tBegin)>
<cfoutput>
    x = #request.x#<br>
    Time to complete: #scriptTime#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It does not appear to be a valid test.  Your custom tag has conditional logic and your function does not.  If you want to compare the two, make them as similar as possible.

Comment: It would also be useful to compare functions inside of components vs functions that are not. Also, what version of CF are you using

Comment: Testing CF10, all updates applied, lastest java applied.  But we can only use CF8 tags because of our customers... * *sigh* *.

Comment: Another improvement you can do is just put `return arguments.numIn++` rather than the 3 lines you have now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing apples to oranges: custom tags and functions are not interchangeable concepts. Whilst they can both be coded to achieve much the same end, it would generally be a poor decision to use a custom tag where a function is appropriate; and equally a poor choice to use a function where a custom tag is a better fit.

Functions are for data manipulation; custom tags are for text / content manipulation. So your functions belong in your business logic, and your custom tags belong in your display logic.

Both have their place.

If you're looping over something 1000 times and calling some functionality 200 times per iteration... that really doesn't sound like you should be using a custom tag (it's not preparing text for output, is it?); it sounds like data-processing, so should be handled by functions (hopefully ones that are encapsulated in objects appropriately...)

Comment: I didn't write this code, just trying to improve it. The custom tags do not prepare output for a browser, the flush data into a PDF that is being built with iText. The custom tag calls some iText code for drawing data in a cell: `<cfset c = p.PdfPCell.init(p.dom[tdIdxBeg+1].pdf)>` after that is init'ed it then calls a handful of `PdfPCell` functions, like: setUseVariableBorders, setUseBorderPadding, setGrayFill, setColspan, setHorizontalAlignment, etc. Then it finally ends by adding the cell to the PDF. So if it were a function is would NOT return anything. Maybe it needs to be a `cfinclude`??

Comment: The whole process is building a PDF on the fly with iText.  Custom tags are used so that writing the PDF looks like you're writing html.  And this entire process is in a loop, so its building 1000s of PDFs on the fly. **I found my memory leak also**, the main loop that is looping the PDFs was in a `cfc` function. I moved it out to it's own `.cfm` file and memory never spiked, it stayed a nice saw tooth. Still trying to figure out why. That cfc it was in was being called every 1sec, but a different function was being called, a function to check it's status, I wonder if that was the problem.